# EclipseLink/JPA and multiple databases with similar structures

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink, ddl

Due decisions out of my control, I have two existing databases which are almost clones.

"Almost" as in there are tables/columns in #1 which does not exist in #2, and vice versa.

What is the best approach here?

The "brute force" route seem to be "create all entities for one, copy to new package and add/remove for second database". Which is not really a route I'd like to go.

Oh, and JPA is definitely not allowed to alter the schema in either database.

Besides EclipseLink, I use Spring 3.1 and SpringData.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into EclipseLink's extensibility support.

You can add a properties Map to the class, and use an orm.xml to map the additional attributes in the other database into this map.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Extensible_Entities

Answer (score 0):

If your databases differ you need to make different classes/mappings. For example, if you have a table `Foo` in both databases which has 3 columns in db1 (`id`, `baz`, `pleh`) and 3 other columns in db2 (`id`, `baz`, `qux`) you cannot do this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo
{
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "baz")
    private String baz;
    @Column(name = "pleh")
    private String pleh;
    @Column(name = "qux")
    private String qux;
}
```

Doing so will result in exceptions as JPA will generate insert statements like:

```
insert into Foo (id, baz, pleh, qux) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

For DB1 you need to create a class `Foo` like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo
{
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "baz")
    private String baz;
    @Column(name = "pleh")
    private String pleh;
}
```

And for DB2 like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo
{
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "baz")
    private String baz;
    @Column(name = "qux")
    private String qux;
}
```